# Need support about BLPOP Predis PHP

Tags: php, redis

I am building chat message system long poll use BLPOP. 
I used Predis PHP.  When I run `test/get` ->it runs okie with 30s timeout.

While running `test/get` I try to push data by `test/push` but it has problem. Push not execute immediately unless `test/get` finished. `test/push` takes 30s.

I use command line to push data: `RPUSH message:test hello` -> It executes immediately and very nice.

```
require './vendor/autoload.php';

class Test extends CI_Controller {
public $keyChat = 'message:test';
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function push() {
    $redis = new Predis\Client(['host' => 'localhost','port' => 6379]);
    $redis->rpush($this->keyChat, 'hello you');
    $redis->expire($this->keyChat, 3600);
    echo "send message success";
}

    public function get() {
        $redis = new Predis\Client(['host' => '127.0.0.1','port' =>   6379]);
        $res = $redis->blpop($this->keyChat, 30);
        var_dump($res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you checked the `BLPOP` documentation, you will find that it is a blocking operation, I suppose that you are trying to push by instantiating another Redis client, so `BLPOP` can find the value and return it.

The 30 seconds issue, is the timeout for `BLPOP` to unblock as in:

`$redis->blpop($this->keyChat, 30);`

The reason it works when you push it from the command line, is that it is a different connection, I am not sure in the case of Predis, but I think the same connection is returned when you try to `RPUSH` , that is why it is giving you that issue.